# Return just the month from a date (as a date, not the month number) - Excel

Tags: excel, int, excel-formula

Is there a way to return/extract just the month from a date in Excel? (Not the number of the month, but the actual integer value?)

Comment: I know this has been answered, but it's not clear to me what you were looking for and why.  Did you just want the first day of the current month, because that is not what I interpreted the question to be!

Comment: Yes, just the first day. Basically I needed to jump back to the first day of any given month, which Excel would provide based on the result of TODAY() when the user entered a workbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

or even simplier: `=EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)+1`

Answer (score 0):

Putting this here because I finally figured this out. Thanks to Barry Houdini (as usual)- almost every solution online is for returning only the month as the month's number (=MONTH(yourdate)) or extracting just the month as text.

This pulled it:

(In my scenario, I only wanted the month integer value for today's date, which is not 3, but 41699)

=INT(TODAY())-DAY(TODAY())+1

Comment: or even simplier: `=EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)+1`

Comment: You don't really need the INT function - you will get an integer with =TODAY()-DAY(TODAY())+1